# jQuery UI buttonset verticaly wonky

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, vertical-alignment, jqueryi-ui-buttonset

Hi I have [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBgEm/) that shows what may be a bug. Note that this is a paste of the derived html - basically I reset the height programmatically so that all the buttons are the same height (should be simple)

For what it's worth: here is the programmatic re-height that I do *after* the butonset() call

```
  fullHeight = 0;
  $('.jQueryUIGrid_topgrid').each(function(){
         fullHeight = ((fullHeight<$(this).height()) ? $(this).outerHeight() : fullHeight);
  });

   $('.jQueryUIGrid_topgrid').each(function(){
        $(this).css('height',fullHeight);
   });
```

The issue isn't just that they are behaving oddly, (up, down, all over the place) it's that I can see no information in firebug as to why this is happening.

Comment: Could you please show a fiddle of the code that generates the situation. Showing just the result is not very useful.

Comment: it's part of an addon I am developing so it's heavily imbedded. It would take me an insane amount of time to unpick it: Needless to say the "bug" looks exactly like it does in the jsFiddle and it's the same graphics on all browsers

Comment: We can wait. Take your time

Comment: ..I did add it it takes ages to load but you can see the bug http://jsfiddle.net/eQau4/1/ the bug is happening around line 162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `vertical-align` on `.ui-button`

```
#jQueryUIGrid_radio .ui-button {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAp2t/3/)

Comment: !thanks! I had tried "div align top" on my own, since I had read it had been a FireFox specific issue a while back  - but that "top" was not seen doing anything and I moved on.. any ideas as to why it was the same effect / same margins on every browser? Looks like a weird "effect" to say the least

Comment: @user2083181 It has to do with the padding on `.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text` set by jQuery  UI. This combined with the set height must cause calculations to become skewed. That is why items with multiple lines of text go higher as the number of lines of text increase.